# In a first-order system of deduction, is $\exists x Px \land \exists x Px$ distinct from $\exists x Px$?

Tags: first-order-logic

It seems to me that given the statement $\exists x Px \land \exists x Px$, we could derive **two** propositions such that $Pa \land Pb$, which is not the case for the statement $\exists x Px$. What I'd like to know is that, formally speaking, within a first-order system of deduction, is $\exists x Px \land \exists x Px$ a well formed sentence whose semantics imply some $Pa$ and another $Pb$, or do we necessarily need to distinguish the quantification, e.g. $\exists x_1 Px_1 \land \exists x_2 Px_2$? I know the statement without distinction is confusing and I'm not planning to use it, I'd just like to know if it would, in a first-order system of deduction, consist in a different statement from the one we'd get with a restate rule:

$\exists x Px$

$[\exists x Px]$(restate rule)

Thank you very much!

Comment: It is not clear exactly what you are asking.  All of the propositions you have written ($\exists x Px$, $\exists x Px \wedge \exists x Px$, and $\exists x_1 Px_1 \land \exists x_2 Px_2$) are logically equivalent.

Comment: @EricWofsey out of the three you've listed, doesn't the third one imply there are two different elements in the domain which make true the truth-function $P$, while the first only implies there is a single one?

Comment: No, because nothing says the two elements of the domain must be different from each other.

Comment: @EricWofsey oh, thank you very much, that's an important distinction!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First of all, for any proposition $P$, $P$ is logically equivalent to $P \land P$. This is quite easy to prove. So $(\exists x P(x))$ is logically equivalent to $(\exists x P(x)) \land (\exists x P(x))$.

Let's dig into this a little bit more.

> What I'd like to know is that, formally speaking, within a first-order system of deduction, is $\exists x P(x) \land \exists x P(x)$ a well formed sentence whose semantics imply some $P(a)$ and another $P(b)$

Yes. However, there is no guarantee that $a$ and $b$ are different. They could be equal (or, if you're not working in a logic with equality, they could be indistinguishable).

> Do we necessarily need to distinguish the quantification, e.g. $\exists x_1 P(x_1) \land \exists x_2 P(x_2)$?

The propositions $\exists x P(x) \land \exists x P(x)$ and $\exists x_1 P(x_1) \land \exists x_2 P(x_2)$ are logically equivalent.

This is because $\exists x P(x)$, $\exists x_1 P(x_1)$, and $\exists x_2 P(x_2)$ are all logically equivalent. In general, if $R$ and $R'$ are logically equivalent and $S$ and $S'$ are logically equivalent, then $R \land S$ and $R' \land S'$ are logically equivalent. Therefore, $\exists x P(x) \land \exists x P(x)$ and $\exists x_1 P(x_1) \land \exists x_2 P(x_2)$ are all logically equivalent.

Comment: Thank you very much for the answer! Just a clarificatory question: would it actually be the case then that, for $\exists x Px \land \exists x Px$, if we let $a,b$ be such that $Pa \land Pb$, then $a$ must (not could) be equal to $b$? I ask since we now know that $\exists x Px$ is equivalent to $\exists x Px \land \exists x Px$

Comment: @shintuku It's possible for $a = b$, and it's also possible that $a \neq b$. We don't know that just from the fact that $Pa \land Pb$. For example, take $P(x) :\equiv (x = x)$. Then knowing $P(a)$ and knowing $P(b)$ does not really tell us anything at all, just that $a = a$ and $b = b$.

Comment: Thank you for the help, it is super appreciated!